# Why use this song in Avengers: Endgame Opening Logo Sequence?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, title-sequence

In the Opening Logo Sequence of Avengers: Endgame they used the song, **Dear Mr. Fantasy**.

**Avengers: Endgame Opening Logo Sequence**

**Dear Mr. Fantasy**

What is the significance of using the song?

Comment: Because its a bad ass song

Answer (score 5):

> Dear Mr. Fantasy play us a tune
> Something to make us all happy
> Do anything, take us out of this gloom
>
> Sing a song, play guitar, make it snappy
>  You are the one who can make us all laugh
>  But doing that you break out in tears
>  Please don't be sad if it was a straight mind you had
> We wouldn't have known you all these years

According to both TV Guide and [Movie Web](https://movieweb.com/avengers-endgame-opening-song-traffic-dear-mr-fantasy/), the song is meant to be about Stark figuring out time travel.

The two sites above, as well as [udiscovermusic](https://www.udiscovermusic.com/news/traffic-dear-mr-fantasy-avengers-endgame/), have all suggested that the song was one of the mp3's on Quill's Zune and was still aboard the Benetar.

As [PopSugar](https://www.popsugar.com/entertainment/photo-gallery/46079665/embed/46079666/embed) points out, the song came out in the 1960s which is the same decade that Iron Man was first introduced (1963) and starred in his own comic (1968).

**Update:**

In the commentary for the film, [Joe Russo](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0751648/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1) said:

> We felt like it was correct tonally, but we thought that the lyrics
> were appropriate for Marvel, and what it’s done and the expectations
> from giant pop culture films.

and [Anthony Russo](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0751577/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1) said:

> This being the climactic movie of the 22-movie run, it was nice to
> comment on our experience of these movies

[Talkies Network](https://talkiesnetwork.com/2019/07/31/avengers-endgame-directors-reveal-why-dear-mr-fantasy-was-chosen-over-marvel-fanfare/) added that:

> the song was meant distinguish the film right off the bat from other
> Marvel features:

Comment: Also, think about the setting of the start of the movie - there's often old songs being played there.  It's not unreasonable to assume that Tony would listen to some of it.

Comment: I interpret it as setting the mode of the movie. Since 50% of the people were gone from the prev movie so this movie is something to make us all happy and take us out of this gloom